# Group a list view by a particular column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, xml

I'm trying to create a ticket system, but I have a small issue.

I'm trying to group the existing items, in categories, based on the drop-down column "Status".

Ex:

- All tickets with status "Open" grouped together,
- all tickets with status "Closed" grouped together, and so on,

so when you click on one  of them, you will see all the items contained in that category.

Does anyone know if there is any possible way to do this using XML?

As I've seen, there is an attribute called "Threaded" that allows this option, but I can't find any working example that could help me understand.

Comment: The Grouping function is not enough I guess? It will not give you a dropdown but it will Group your items based on a field value (like your Status)

Comment: If you're reffering to the same grouping function as Karthik, then it's not much of a use ..
If not, please suggest a refference, o i can see more exactly how it works.
Thank you very much, Calin

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint List View in default provides the "Group By" functionality. Goto List Sessting --> Edit View and there you can find "Group By" options. A SharePoint List View can be grouped by 2 columns values in default.

Reference Links:

1. https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/sharepoint-group-by-a-column-with-multiple-values.aspx

1.1  http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-sharepoint-services-help/organize-items-in-a-list-HA010024478.aspx

Comment: That is true Karthik, but i need a solution from visual studio, so that after the project is deployed, the end users don't need to do any additional clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for Schema.xml of the list. In View tag, add

`<Query>
    <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE">
        <FieldRef Name="Status" />
    </GroupBy>
</Query`

For more reference, you can try to create a list, modify the view to your needs,
save as it as a template from its List Settings and download the .stp file from List Template Gallery.

Change .stp namespace to .cab, look for its Manifest.xml inside and search for  tag.
Also look for the  tag as your question was you wanted to show only "Open" and "Closed" status